# How can we call user defined function from classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have a query like this

```
select distinct mydb.getprodsizecolor(idProduct,'%color%') as icolor from products
```

I am calling this from my asp page and its working fine,

I have to store '%color' in a variable like

```
desc = '%color%'
```

But when i execute query like this, it errors out

```
select distinct mydb.getprodsizecolor(idProduct,desc) as icolor from products
```

can any one help ?

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be in a string format

```
query = "select distinct mydb.getprodsizecolor(idProduct,'%color%') as icolor from products"
```

So when you are assigning the value in a variable you can try it this way

```
desc = "'%color%'" 
query = "select distinct mydb.getprodsizecolor(idProduct,"&desc&") as icolor from products"
```

Comment: wouldn't it be? `desc = "'%color%'"` if he needs the ticks that is